# MySQL won't start on xampp (Windows)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

This problem started when I didn't properly hibernate my laptop. Every time I open xampp, I can't start MySQL. I searched for online answers but nothing happened. I tried changing the port from 3306 to 3307 to 80, still nothing happened.

So I uninstalled xampp and install it again. After installing, I tried to start Apache and MySQL. Worked fine with Apache but on MySQL, I got this error log:

```
4:52:15 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
4:52:15 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
4:52:15 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:52:15 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:52:15 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:52:15 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
4:52:15 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Why not follow the instructions and check the logs?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually because of Skype (or any other program that uses MySql port). Go to Skype `Options > Advanced > Connection` type in alternative port (e.g. 42795) and uncheck "Use port 80 and 443..."